# What is the need of defining the Argument variable inside the function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, function

What is the need of defining the argument variable inside the function?

```
def load_housing_data(housing_path=HOUSING_PATH):
 

 csv_path = os.path.join(housing_path, "housing.csv")
 return pd.read_csv(csv_path)
```

Can't we simply ignore it like -

```
def load_housing_data():
 

  csv_path = os.path.join(HOUSING_PATH, "housing.csv")
  return pd.read_csv(csv_path)
```

I'm believe -

```
def load_housing_data():
```

is more right than -

```
def load_housing_data(housing_path=HOUSING_PATH):
```

Answer (score 0):

`def load_housing_data(housing_path=HOUSING_PATH):`
argument housing_path have HOUSING_PATH as default value, that means, if you call function `load_housing_data()` and no passed that argument, by default taken HOUSING_PATH as value

Answer (score 0):

Both ways will work.

In the first one you are defaulting the argument to a value. This allows you to skip supplying one if the default value is sufficient, but still allows you to supply an alternate if it is not sufficient.

```
def load_housing_data(housing_path=HOUSING_PATH):
   csv_path = os.path.join(housing_path, "housing.csv")
   return pd.read_csv(csv_path)

#you can do this
data = load_housing_data()

#or this
data = load_housing_data(SOME_OTHER_PATH)
```

In the second you are statically supplying the value and removing your ability to supply an alternate one.

```
def load_housing_data():
    csv_path = os.path.join(HOUSING_PATH, "housing.csv")
    return pd.read_csv(csv_path)

#only option
data = load_housing_data()
```

However, if you are going to use the second version, then you might as well make `csv_path` global. You've made it so `csv_path` will never be different so, no reason to keep remaking it every time you call the `def`.

```
CSV_PATH = os.path.join(HOUSING_PATH, "housing.csv")

def load_housing_data():
    return pd.read_csv(CSV_PATH)
```

Once you do that, the `def` is essentially just an alias so, you don't need it.

```
CSV_PATH = os.path.join(HOUSING_PATH, "housing.csv")
data     = pd.read_csv(CSV_PATH)
```